# How to set different IP for client and server running on same machine?

Tags: python, serversocket

I used socket module and localhost IP address 127.0.0.1 and both client and server are under same IP (codes written in python and socket modules are imported)
How I use different IP address to server and client if you know please let me know it’s very important

Comment: You need to route a specific IP to `localhost`. See: https://superuser.com/questions/363036/how-to-map-an-ip-adress-to-localhost or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/441182/how-to-map-an-ip-address-to-localhost

Comment: Please explain why you need to use a different IP address and how this question is related to software development!